# Sails.js Custom View for JSON

Tags: node.js, sails.js

How can we have a custom json on a Sails Model?

I created a inventory model

````
```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    id: {type: 'integer'},
    quantity: {type: 'integer'},
    name: {type: 'string'},
    description: {type: 'string'}
  }

```
````

However, the default model I get have additional attributes like createdAt , updateAt

```
Inventory.find({}).sort('id asc').exec(function(err, i){console.log}
```

I would like to have custom attributes on json, like add some attributes
I know we can custom make by writting code on controller.

But can we have custom view on json? like ruby Jbuilder., write now `res.view()` only supports HTML.

Answer (score 2):

First you can use `res.json()` instead of `res.view()` or `rest.ok()` will automatically negotiate between JSON and HTML.

Sails.js allows you to customize the JSON of a particular model or you can just customize your blanket response type or you can attach whatever custom attributes you want to your JSON object that you want to send back in your controller.

Using the `.toJson()` override in your model
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/records/to-json
https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/instance-class-methods.md#toobjecttojson

or create custom response types like `res.myJson()`
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/custom-responses

Or lastly, in your controller you can create whatever object you want and just pass it back with `res.toJson()`